# When should I use FrameworkPropertyMetadata or UIPropertyMetadata over plain PropertyMetadata?

Tags: wpf, attached-properties, attachedbehaviors

When looking at sample attached properties and behaviors, I've seen a mishmash of uses of `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`, `UIPropertyMetadata` and `PropertyMetadata`. Since they all form an inheritance hierarchy, how do I choose which one to use?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

These classes are to report some behavior aspects of a dependency property.

Check the different classes for the options they provide.

For example,

if you just want to back a property by dp and provide a default value, use `PropertyMetadata`,

if you want to specify animation behavior, use `UIPropertyMetadata`,

but if some property affects wpf framework level stuffs eg element layout, parent layout or databinding, use `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`.

Details you can check on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751554.aspx

Comment: The real question is, why does the propdp snippet use UIPropertyMetadata, especially since there are no PropertyMetadata subclasses in Silverlight?  It drives me nuts.

Comment: That's because same snippets are shared between WPF and Silverlight.
You can try different snippets for silverlight from this link:
http://blog.nerdplusart.com/archives/silverlight-code-snippets

Comment: MSDN says "In general, you should use FrameworkPropertyMetadata, particularly if your property has any interaction with property system and WPF functions such as layout and data binding." - (Specifying Metadata) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751554.aspx

Comment: What kind of data binding should FrameworkPropertyMetadata be used for? I simply want a property that is bound to IsEnabled of a control.

Answer (score 1):

One useful feature of `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` is that you can define the behaviour `BindsTwoWayByDefault`. Otherwise the dependency property is *OneWay* by default.

When you need a **two way binding** for a dependency property, then normally you always need to define `Mode=TwoWay` for each binding. If you set this mode as default, you don't need to set it for each binding anymore.

You set the behaviour like this:

```
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(_myDefaultValue_, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault)
```

Complete example:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(MyClass),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault);

public bool IsSelected
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value); }
}
```