# DependencyProperty fails to create proper UpdateSourceTrigger inside binding when the binding has not set UpdateSourceTrigger explicitly

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, dependency-properties

@update - See update below, please

I've got the `UserControl` that is used inside `DataGridTemplateColumn`. When I specify the binding like this `{Binding MyProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}` it updates the source. However then I ommit `UpdateSourceTrigger` it doesn't update the source.

The `DependencyProperty` is created like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RatingValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "RatingValue", typeof(int?), typeof(RatingControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(int),
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
        DependencyPropertyChangedCallback,
        CoerceRatingValueCallback,
        false,
        UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
));
```

As you can see below, the `Binding` is created with `Default` flag when the `UpdateSourceTrigger` is omitted, and with `PropertyChanged` flag if not.

The "not working" binding (see line 26 on both examples):

```
0   _binding    {System.Windows.Data.Binding}   System.Windows.Data.BindingBase {System.Windows.Data.Binding}
1   AsyncState  null    object
2   BindingGroupName    ""  string
3   BindsDirectlyToSource   false   bool
4   Converter   null    System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
5   ConverterCulture    null    System.Globalization.CultureInfo
6   ConverterCultureInternal    null    System.Globalization.CultureInfo
7   ConverterParameter  null    object
8   Delay   0   int
9   ElementName null    string
10  FallbackValue   {{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}}   object {MS.Internal.NamedObject}
11  Flags   Default System.Windows.Data.BindingBase.BindingFlags
12  IsAsync false   bool
13  Mode    Default System.Windows.Data.BindingMode
14  NotifyOnSourceUpdated   false   bool
15  NotifyOnTargetUpdated   false   bool
16  NotifyOnValidationError false   bool
17  Path    {System.Windows.PropertyPath}   System.Windows.PropertyPath
18  RelativeSource  null    System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource
19  Source  null    object
20  SourceReference null    MS.Internal.Data.ObjectRef
21  StringFormat    null    string
22  TargetNullValue {{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}}   object {MS.Internal.NamedObject}
23  TransfersDefaultValue   true    bool
24  TreeContextIsRequired   false   bool
25  UpdateSourceExceptionFilter null    System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceExceptionFilterCallback
26  UpdateSourceTrigger Default System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger
27  ValidatesOnDataErrors   false   bool
28  ValidatesOnExceptions   false   bool
29  ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors true    bool
30  ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrorsInternal true    bool
31  ValidationRules Count = 0   System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.Windows.Controls.ValidationRule> {MS.Internal.Controls.ValidationRuleCollection}
32  ValidationRulesInternal Count = 0   System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.Windows.Controls.ValidationRule> {MS.Internal.Controls.ValidationRuleCollection}
33  XPath   null    string
34  _attachedPropertiesInPath   0   int
35  _bindsDirectlyToSource  false   bool
36  _doesNotTransferDefaultValue    false   bool
37  _flags  Default System.Windows.Data.BindingBase.BindingFlags
38  _isAsync    false   bool
39  _isSealed   true    bool
40  _ppath  {System.Windows.PropertyPath}   System.Windows.PropertyPath
41  _source {MS.Internal.Data.ExplicitObjectRef}    MS.Internal.Data.ObjectRef {MS.Internal.Data.ExplicitObjectRef}
42  _sourceInUse    None    System.Windows.Data.Binding.SourceProperties
43  _values {MS.Internal.UncommonValueTable}    MS.Internal.UncommonValueTable
44  Static members
```

The "working" binding:

```
0   _binding    {System.Windows.Data.Binding}   System.Windows.Data.BindingBase {System.Windows.Data.Binding}
1   AsyncState  null    object
2   BindingGroupName    ""  string
3   BindsDirectlyToSource   false   bool
4   Converter   null    System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
5   ConverterCulture    null    System.Globalization.CultureInfo
6   ConverterCultureInternal    null    System.Globalization.CultureInfo
7   ConverterParameter  null    object
8   Delay   0   int
9   ElementName null    string
10  FallbackValue   {{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}}   object {MS.Internal.NamedObject}
11  Flags   PropDefault | ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors   System.Windows.Data.BindingBase.BindingFlags
12  IsAsync false   bool
13  Mode    Default System.Windows.Data.BindingMode
14  NotifyOnSourceUpdated   false   bool
15  NotifyOnTargetUpdated   false   bool
16  NotifyOnValidationError false   bool
17  Path    {System.Windows.PropertyPath}   System.Windows.PropertyPath
18  RelativeSource  null    System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource
19  Source  null    object
20  SourceReference null    MS.Internal.Data.ObjectRef
21  StringFormat    null    string
22  TargetNullValue {{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}}   object {MS.Internal.NamedObject}
23  TransfersDefaultValue   true    bool
24  TreeContextIsRequired   false   bool
25  UpdateSourceExceptionFilter null    System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceExceptionFilterCallback
26  UpdateSourceTrigger PropertyChanged System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger
27  ValidatesOnDataErrors   false   bool
28  ValidatesOnExceptions   false   bool
29  ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors true    bool
30  ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrorsInternal true    bool
31  ValidationRules Count = 0   System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.Windows.Controls.ValidationRule> {MS.Internal.Controls.ValidationRuleCollection}
32  ValidationRulesInternal Count = 0   System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.Windows.Controls.ValidationRule> {MS.Internal.Controls.ValidationRuleCollection}
33  XPath   null    string
34  _attachedPropertiesInPath   0   int
35  _bindsDirectlyToSource  false   bool
36  _doesNotTransferDefaultValue    false   bool
37  _flags  PropDefault | ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors   System.Windows.Data.BindingBase.BindingFlags
38  _isAsync    false   bool
39  _isSealed   true    bool
40  _ppath  {System.Windows.PropertyPath}   System.Windows.PropertyPath
41  _source {MS.Internal.Data.ExplicitObjectRef}    MS.Internal.Data.ObjectRef {MS.Internal.Data.ExplicitObjectRef}
42  _sourceInUse    None    System.Windows.Data.Binding.SourceProperties
43  _values {MS.Internal.UncommonValueTable}    MS.Internal.UncommonValueTable
44  Static members
```

How to solve this so I don't have to set "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" explicitly in WPF.

@update 2017-06-03

I have attached link ([click](https://github.com/tariel36/so_44248130)) to the example project to illustrate the issue. Please open MainWindow.xaml and fiddle with lines #35-#39. The line #36 presents the not-working behaviour, the line #39 presents the working behaviour.

Line #36

```
<local:RatingControl StarsCount="5" RatingValue="{Binding Rating, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" IsReadonly="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
```

Line #39

```
<local:RatingControl StarsCount="5" RatingValue="{Binding Rating, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" IsReadonly="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
```

@Edit - Requested XAML code

```
<UserControl x:Class="so_44248130.RatingControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="24" d:DesignWidth="240">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
        <BitmapImage x:Key="StarEmpty" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/so_44248130;component/star_black_empty.png" CacheOption="OnLoad" CreateOptions="IgnoreImageCache" />
        <BitmapImage x:Key="StarFull" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/so_44248130;component/star_black_full.png" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StarsList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="24" Height="24" MaxHeight="24" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Tag="{Binding}" Padding="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="{Binding EmptyStarWidth}" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource StarEmpty}"
                                        TileMode="Tile"
                                        Stretch="Uniform"
                                        AlignmentY="Top"
                                        Viewport="0,0,24,3000"
                                        ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                                <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="{Binding FullStarWidth}" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource StarFull}"
                                        TileMode="Tile"
                                        Stretch="Uniform"
                                        AlignmentY="Top"
                                        Viewport="0,0,24,3000"
                                        ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                            </Grid>
                        </Button>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="24" Width="24" Visibility="{Binding IsReadonly, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Fill="#02FFFFFF" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: The value of the `DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger` property of the FrameworkPropertyMetadata class is `PropertyChanged` anyway, so you could use a FrameworkPropertyMetadata constructor with less parameters. That said, all dependency properties with `BindsTwoWayByDefault` that I've ever created do update their source on `PropertyChanged` without problems, so it's unclear why yours doesn't.

Comment: @Clemens I've edited my question (added link to example project), please see for yourself

Comment: Can we see RatingControl's XAML?

Comment: @EdPlunkett There's link to example project at the bottom of the question which contains RatingControl's XAML and CS. - https://github.com/tariel36/so_44248130/blob/master/so_44248130/RatingControl.xaml

Comment: Please add it to the question. If it's on an external site, it'll be a dead link sooner or later, and in any case you can't ask people to dig through a github project to find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out... partially...

In the example project linked in question one should navigate to `RatingControl.xaml.cs` file, lines #206-#228 ([click](https://github.com/tariel36/so_44248130/blob/master/so_44248130/RatingControl.xaml.cs#L226)). This is the `ButtonBase_OnClick` method. Just under `if (star.Value ==`~ part I've added the force `UpdateSource` of binding. See code below.

```
if (star.Value == RatingValue)
{
    RatingValue = 0;
}
else
{
    RatingValue = star.Value;
}

BindingExpression binding = GetBindingExpression(RatingValueProperty);
if (binding != null)
{
    binding.UpdateSource();
}
```

which forces the update of `BindingSource` and resolves the issue (it's some kind of workaround probably.. but maybe it will put someone in the right direction to post the real valid answer).

Note:

While debugging I've inspected the received `BindingExpression` and the property named `IsUpdateOnPropertyChanged` is set to `false` for some reason. I belive it should be set to `true` however I lack the knowledge about `WPF` internals to post it as answer, hence the "note" region.

Answer (score -1):

Is there any specific reason for using `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`?

if you are just backing up a property then try using `PropertyMetadata`.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486999/when-should-i-use-frameworkpropertymetadata-or-uipropertymetadata-over-plain-pro) for more details.

Comment: No specific reason. I've changed `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` to `PropertyMetadata` however the only result is that I have to specify `Mode=TwoWay` in XAML's `Binding` explicitly, so.. didn't really help :(.

Comment: I got the issue its because it not able to find the source, try `<local:RatingControl StarsCount="5" RatingValue="{Binding DataContext.Rating, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell,Mode=FindAncestor}, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" IsReadonly="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />`

Comment: Yes it seems to help however it looks like another workaround, could you elaborate why it's not able to find the source even if `DataContext` is inherited by UC?

Comment: Even though the UC inherists the `DataContext`, `DataTempelete` has some issue with `DataContext`.  I my experience I came across a scenario where `DataTemplete` was unable to find the Governing `FrameworkElement` i.e. its ancestor. You can google for (unable to find the Governing `FrameworkElement`) and there are tons of article lying down over internet.